# rabbitmq management api documentation about the arguments of json response of api

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying monitor all the queues of my rabbitmq server using RabbitMQ Management HTTP API. I need detailed documentation about all the arguments returned in json by 
localhost:15672/api/queues

Comment: Have you tried the official site? https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html

Comment: check this:
http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/31c1d2668d39/priv/www/doc/stats.html

Comment: You are welcome @hritik. I copy the answer for future reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link:

http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/31c1d2668d39/priv/www/doc/stats.html

> Most of the GET requests you can issue to the HTTP API return JSON objects with a large number of keys. While a few of these keys represent things you set yourself in a PUT request or AMQP command (e.g. queue durability or arguments), most of them represent statistics to do with the object in question. This page attempts to document them.